# Sending multiple POST data in Python

Tags: python, post, request

I have a Python code that sends POST request to a website, reads the response and filters it. For the POST data I used ('number', '11111') and it works perfect. However, I want to create a txt file that contains 100 different numbers as 1111,2222,3333,4444... and then send the POST requests for each of them. Can you help me how to do this in Python?

```html
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Origin': 'http://mahmutesat.com/python.aspx',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer': 'http://mahmutesat.com/python.aspx',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
}

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'

myopener = MyOpener()
url = 'http://mahmutesat.com/python.aspx'
# first HTTP request without form data
f = myopener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
# parse and retrieve two vital form values
viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
viewstategenerator = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']

formData = (
    ('__EVENTVALIDATION', eventvalidation),
    ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
    ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR',viewstategenerator),
    ('number', '11111'),
    ('Button', 'Sorgula'),   
)

encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formData)
# second HTTP request with form data
f = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)

soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

name=soup.findAll('input',{'id':'name_field'})

for eachname in name:
   print eachname['value']
```

Comment: Read the file with data `1111,2222,3333,4444,..` split the string on `,` and loop through the data. Did you try that?

Comment: I thought about that but I could not write the code. Can you give me an example code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file has data:

"sample.txt"

```
1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,......(and so on)
```

To read the file contents, you can use the file `open` operation:

```
import itertools

#open the file for read
with open("sample.txt", "r") as fp:
     values = fp.readlines()

#Get the values split with ","
data = [map(int, line.split(",")) for line in values]
numbers = list(itertools.chain(*data)) #Ensuring if its having many lines then concatenate
```

Now, use it as:

```
for number in numbers:
    formData = (
        ('__EVENTVALIDATION', eventvalidation),
        ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
        ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR',viewstategenerator),
        ('number', str(number)), # Here you use the number obtained
        ('Button', 'Sorgula'),   
    )

    encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formData)
    # second HTTP request with form data
    f = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

    name=soup.findAll('input',{'id':'name_field'})

    for eachname in name:
       print eachname['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Here is an example on how to create a file:

```
f = open('test.txt','w')
```

This will open the `test.txt` file for writing (`'w'`) (if it has already data, it will be erased but if you want to append it write: `f = open('test.txt','a')` ) or create one if it does not exist yet. Note that this will happen in your current working directory, if you want it in a specific directory, include with the file name the full directory path, example:

```
f = open('C:\\Python\\test.txt','w')
```

2 - Then write/append to this file the data you want, example:

```
for i in range(1,101):
     f.write(str(i*1111)+'\n')
```

This will write 100 numbers as string from 1111 to 111100

3 - You should always close the file at the end:

```
f.close()
```

4 - Now if you want to read from this file '`test.txt`':

```
f = open('C:\\Python\\test.txt','r')
for i in f:
print i,
file.close()
```

This is as simple as it can be,

You need to read about File I/O in python from:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Make sure you select the right Python version for you in this docs.

Answer (score 0):

## using dictionary you can deal with the multiple requests, very easily.

import requests

```
values = {

    '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation, 
    '__LASTFOCUS': '', 
    '__VIEWSTATE': view_state, 
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '6264FB8D', 
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButGet': 'Get Report',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Ddl_Circles': 'All Circles', 
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Ddl_Divisions': '-- Select --', 
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TxtTin': tin_num, 
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dropact': 'all' 
    
}



headers_1 = {

        'Origin': 'https://www.apct.gov.in', 
        'User-Agent': user_agent,
        'Cookie': cookie_1, 
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
        'Referer': url_1,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1' 
        
}


try:
    req = requests.post(url_1, data=values, headers=headers_1)
```